# SubSonic Controller

Tags: subsonic, controller

What's the use of the controllers in SubSonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the controllers work with the ObjectDataSouce.

If you aren't using ODS, there is a config setting called generateODSControllers which you can set to false to prevent the controllers from being generated.

[More info on ODS/Controller usage (scroll down)](http://www.codeplex.com/subsonic/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Examples&referringTitle=Docs)